# what is STATUS in C? Is it a keyword /definition / return value?

Tags: c

```
void slpEnableService (void)
{

    STATUS status;
    slp_task_msg_t msg;
    int slpEventBuf = 1;

    msg.id = SLP_MSG_ENABLE;
    status = msgQSend(slp_msg_queue, (char *)&msg, sizeof(slp_task_msg_t),
            NO_WAIT, MSG_PRI_NORMAL);
    assert(status == OK);
    write(slp_fifo_wr_fd, &slpEventBuf, sizeof(slpEventBuf)); 

}
```

what is STATUS here?

Comment: It's a variable of `STATUS` type (unless it's a macro)

Comment: Identifiers in CAPITALS are usually macros defined either in one of the `#include`d headers or near the top of the code file. So, what headers are  `#include`d?

Comment: All uppercase identifiers are usually macros or enums.  You have to look at the library declaration to make sure, but pretty likely to be an enum.  It can be OK or ERROR.  Also all uppercase, enums are tricky because they can easily cause identifier name collisions and having it named "error" would be rather bad.  Well, not that ERROR is much better, somebody else likely thought of that as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "STATUS" in C.

It's probably defined in a header that we don't know.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a structure/macros/enum , check in your header files which are included in your present code file.

without knowing what things are present in your header file , it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it is all in upper case, it is probably a `#define` macro.

Given it's location - it is where you would expect to see the type in a variable declaration - it is probably a macro that defines a type.

Given that it is used as the return type for `msgQSend()`, it is probably an integer type, in fact, it is probably `int`.

Somewhere in your code (probably in a header) there will be a line like

```
#define STATUS int
```

or possibly

```
typedef int STATUS;
```

or possibly even an enum

```
typedef enum { OK = 0, ERROR = -1 } STATUS;
```